# how to change the placement of the indicators of a custom bootstrap carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I`ve made some changes to the bootstrap carousel so the indicators are images but i want the images indicators to be lined up vertically to the left side, outside the carousel.

this is the css i have so far.

```
#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators {
        margin: 10px 0 0;
        overflow: auto;
        position: static;
        text-align: left;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: 100%;
    }

#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators li {
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 !important;
    width: auto;
}
#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators li img {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators li.active img {
    opacity: 1;
}
#carousel-custom .carousel-indicators li:hover img {
    opacity: 0.75;
}
#carousel-custom .carousel-outer {
    position: relative;
}`
```

and this is the carousel

```
<div class="container">
<div id='carousel-custom' class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel'>
    <div class='carousel-outer'>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class='carousel-inner'>
            <div class='item active'>
                <img src='http://placehold.it/1140x400&text=slide1' alt='' />
            </div>
            <div class='item'>
                <img src='http://placehold.it/1140x400&text=slide2' alt='' />
            </div>
            <div class='item'>
                <img src='http://placehold.it/1140x400&text=slide3' alt='' />
            </div>

            <div class='item'>
                <img src='http://placehold.it/1140x400&text=slide4' alt='' />
            </div>
            <div class='item'>
                <img src='http://placehold.it/1140x400&text=slide5' alt='' />
            </div>
            <div class='item'>
                <img src='http://placehold.it/1140x400&text=slide6' alt='' />
            </div>

            <div class='item'>
                <img src='http://placehold.it/1140x400&text=slide7' alt='' />
            </div>
            <div class='item'>
                <img src='http://placehold.it/1140x400&text=slide8' alt='' />
            </div>
            <div class='item'>
                <img src='http://placehold.it/1140x400&text=slide9' alt='' />
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class='left carousel-control' href='#carousel-custom' data-slide='prev'>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left'></span>
        </a>
        <a class='right carousel-control' href='#carousel-custom' data-slide='next'>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class='carousel-indicators'>
        <li data-target='#carousel-custom' data-slide-to='0' class='active'><img src='http://placehold.it/100x50&text=slide1' alt='' /></li>
        <li data-target='#carousel-custom' data-slide-to='1'><img src='http://placehold.it/100x50&text=slide2' alt='' /></li>
        <li data-target='#carousel-custom' data-slide-to='2'><img src='http://placehold.it/100x50&text=slide3' alt='' /></li>
        <li data-target='#carousel-custom' data-slide-to='3'><img src='http://placehold.it/100x50&text=slide4' alt='' /></li>
        <li data-target='#carousel-custom' data-slide-to='4'><img src='http://placehold.it/100x50&text=slide5' alt='' /></li>
        <li data-target='#carousel-custom' data-slide-to='5'><img src='http://placehold.it/100x50&text=slide6' alt='' /></li>
        <li data-target='#carousel-custom' data-slide-to='6'><img src='http://placehold.it/100x50&text=slide7' alt='' /></li>
        <li data-target='#carousel-custom' data-slide-to='7'><img src='http://placehold.it/100x50&text=slide8' alt='' /></li>
        <li data-target='#carousel-custom' data-slide-to='8'><img src='http://placehold.it/100x50&text=slide9' alt='' /></li>
    </ol>
</div>
</div>
```